# How to insert only results of R1C1 formula calculation without inserting formulas

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to skip a step of inserting a R1C1 formula into range but insert only formula results? What I have now:

```
newColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-17],14,3)"
newColumn.Value = newColumn.Value
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
newColumn.Value = newColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-17],14,3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

newColumn.Value = evaluate("MID(RC[-17],14,3)")

Comment: I think it's ok to go this way for formulas without R1C1 reference. It returns me a `#VALUE!` error

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to convert R1C1 formula to A1 type:

```
Function MakeA1(R1C1Formula As String) As String

MakeA1 = Application.ConvertFormula( _
    Formula:=R1C1Formula, _
    fromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
    toReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
    ToAbsolute:=xlAbsolute)    
End Function
```

Then you can use it so:

```
Sub test()
    str1 = MakeA1("MID(RC[-17],1,3)")
    Range("B2").Value = Evaluate(str1)
End Sub
```